# Cannot instantiate the type Rectangle

Tags: java

I am currently studying java. One of my assignments requires us to write some inheritance code that will display a rectangle in the console of Eclipse. I keep getting the error in my title when trying to run it but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

**TestShape.java**

```
public class TestShape {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double width = 5, length = 7;
        Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(width, length);
        System.out.println("Rectangle width: " + width + " and length: " + length
                + "\nResulting area: " + rectangle.area()
                + "\nResulting perimeter: " + rectangle.perimeter() + "\n");
    }

}
```

**Shape.java**

```
public abstract class Shape {

        public abstract double area();
        public abstract double perimeter();
        public double getArea() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        public double getPerimeter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
    public abstract class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private final double width, height, area, perimeter;

  public Rectangle(double width, double height) {

    this.width = width;

    this.height= height;

    this.area = width * height;

    this.perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
  }

  @Override

  public double getArea() {

    return this.area;

  }

  @Override

  public double getPerimeter() {

    return this.perimeter;

  }

}
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class as you do

Comment: You can't instantiate abstract classes - they can only be inherited from. Remove `abstract` from the definition of the `Rectangle` class.

Comment: Why is your Rectangle class abstract?

Comment: and make sure you import the right rectangle as there are by default 3 different ones

Comment: dont define the rectangle class abstract...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined 2 abstract methods in Shape class, these needs to be either implemented by Rectangle class or Rectangle class needs to be abstract. If you make Rectangle abstract, you will not be able to instantiate. In order to get your code working with minimal changes please chhange your **Rectangle** class implementation to:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private final double width, height, area, perimeter;

    public Rectangle(final double width, final double height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.area = width * height;
        this.perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return this.perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return getArea();
    }

    @Override
    public double perimeter() {
        return getPerimeter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing is you cannot instantiate `abstract class`:

```
Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(width, length);
```

And you cannot remove `abstract` keyword in  `Rectangle` class because two methods are did not implemented in `Shape` class.

```
public abstract double area();
public abstract double perimeter();
```

To instantiate you need to create concreate class or can implement all the method in `Rectangle` class, which methods are inherited from `Shape` class.

Since `area()` and `perimeter()` are features of `Rectangle` class you can implement those two methods and remove `abstract` from `Rectangle` class(now this class is a concrete class). Then, you can instantiate `Rectangle` class in main.